# CSS only navigation - radio box show/hide pages

Tags: html, css, navigation, css-selectors

I'm trying to make a site navigation bar using `radio boxes`,
where pages are shown depending on which is checked.

I can make it work with `<a href='#div'></a>` and  a `:target`,
and if I put the `.page` div right after the `<label>`.

But can't figure out how to do it with `<input type='radio'>` and
markup as below.

Can this be done?

The markup is simple:

```css
.page {
  display: none;
}

#pages > div:<the-missing-part> {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="toolbar">

  <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radios" value="div1">
  <label for="radio1">Div #1</label>

  <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radios" value="div2">
  <label for="radio2">Div #2</label>

  <input type="radio" id="radio3" name="radios" value="div3">
  <label for="radio3">Div #3</label>

</div>

<div id="pages">

  <div id="div1" class="page">Page #1</div>

  <div id="div2" class="page">Page #2</div>

  <div id="div3" class="page">Page #3</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do that the *pages* and *checkboxes* need to share the same *parent element* so that you can link them with the *general sibling combinator* (`~`):

```css
.page {
  display: none;
}

#radio1:checked ~ #div1,
#radio2:checked ~ #div2,
#radio3:checked ~ #div3 {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="toolbar">
  <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radios" value="div1">
  <label for="radio1">Div #1</label>

  <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radios" value="div2">
  <label for="radio2">Div #2</label>

  <input type="radio" id="radio3" name="radios" value="div3">
  <label for="radio3">Div #3</label>

  <div id="div1" class="page">Page #1</div>
  <div id="div2" class="page">Page #2</div>
  <div id="div3" class="page">Page #3</div>
</div>
```